# Where does ClickOnce store update interval information

Tags: clickonce

I've published a ClickOnce and need to change the update frequency (I will use powershell), however I'm having trouble finding out where this information is being stored.

I've checked the following files:

- Setup.exe (bootstrapper) -help doesn't provide update configuration info.
- Application manifest
- Deployment manifest

Is the update frequency configuration embedded in the setup bootstrapper? If so I'll just need to generate a new one from the command line.

I was looking [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165431.aspx) under Publishing Properties, but didn't see anything that suggested on where that configuration ultimately gets stored and whether you can change it via command line or other.

Comment: Did you end up working this out?

Comment: No, I never could find out where it was stored.

Answer (score 1):

It is stored in the manifest-file (could be found under /appdata/Local/Apps/2.0/3P03R6ZA.EH4/7RM98Z2V.B0H/YourAddIn/Addin.dll.manifest

```
<vstav3:update enabled="true">
  <vstav3:expiration maximumAge="1" unit="hours" />
</vstav3:update>
```

just change it and restart your OfficeApplication